# Bash executes comands out of sequance sometimes

Tags: bash, ssh

I running multiple commands in bash in parallel and need to get output that is delimited so receiving script could separate the values.

I attempted to do this in few ways  but it seems that any echo is executed instantly and anything following after.
So I am trying to find a way to separate input from each output with separator preceding output. 
I actually use curl request that may take 50-200ms to respond, but here for simplicity I will give example with time command.

Here is rough example:

```
echo ">" && time &
echo ">" && time &
echo ">" && time &

wait
```

This produces `>>> time time time`

I am looking for a way to make it produce `>time>time>time`

I had some success trying to call other bash scripts with trailing echo command instead of making actual commands and that works most of the time but inevitably things get mixed up because of timing.

I will post updates as I work on it, thank you for the help

Comment: You need each command to write to a separate file, then concatenate the files in the desired order as each background job completes.

Comment: It produces ``bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'`` for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo ">$(time)" &
echo ">$(time) &
echo ">$(time)" &

wait
```

That tells echo that it needs the output of the `time` command you have before it can do its thing.

Comment: This does provide a solution to ops problem. However, it doesn't mention what is wrong with the original approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, simple and elegant solution.

Comment: sjsam, issue with original approach is that bash returns responses as they arrive.
If you want the system to "echo" something and then execute some command, it is possible that command will execute before "echo" posts the text. Results are just posted as soon as they becomes available, this does not allow you to reliably tag them. Solution that worked places output in to echo making it wait for result before it could be posted.